# how to add the dynamically quantity with buynow button in woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

The buy now button on single product page as is presently, is redirecting straight to checkout after adding 1 product to the cart.

What is to be done is that the user selected quantity should ideally be fed to the buy now button dynamically and in real time (through ajax) so that the customer can select the quantity and then decide whether he wants to add the quantity to the cart and continue shopping or he wants to click buy now and add the selected quantity to the cart and being redirected straight to the checkout.

Please refer to the way system works now for better idea how this should work as currently the system works flawlessly apart from allowing to specify desired quantity.

here is the link of my website
http://www.merc-clinic.com/product/lockout-safety-valve-and-electrical-lockout-kit-large/

i am adding this code in  themes/ls_new/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php

```
 <form id="qty" class="cart single-product" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="/checkout?set-cart-qty_<?php echo $product->id;?>=2">
<button id="buynow" type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="<?php echo get_option('tooltip_text');?>" class="single_product_buy_now single_add_to_cart_button button alt cart-buttton buy-now">Buy Now</button>
<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
```

Comment: Given link is not working for me .. It is showing that "Webpage is not available" .

Comment: given link is single product page link 
try this http://www.merc-clinic.com/

Comment: I tried to go with that also but same result...

Comment: can you please change your ip maybe it's ban in your country

Comment: Zenmate Chrome Extenshion is best for changing ip's

Answer (score 0):

I do see you have some format errors and the form ending is missing. I don't use tooltip, but if this works then try adding your title.

Try this:

```
<form id="qty" class="cart single-product" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="quantity"><input class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" max="94" min="1" 
         name="quantity" pattern="[0-9]*" size="4" step="1" type="number" value="1" />
    </div>
    <input name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="2" />
    <button id="buynow" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" 
        type="submit"> Buy Now</button>
</form>
```